# Prepend after animation

Tags: jquery

I want to animate a `div` into another `div` and then prepend it to the `div` it animates to. I have a function called `move_to_inventory` which animates the `div`. After that is done I want prepend_items to fire. But I can't get it to work. Where am I doing this wrong?

```
function move_to_inventory(spelPlan){
    $(spelPlan).children('.box').each(function() {
        $(this).one('click', function(){
            var inventoryPos = $("#inventory").position();
            $(this).animate({
                width: ($(this).width()/2),
                height: ($(this).height()/2),
                left:inventoryPos.left+13,
                top:inventoryPos.top+12
            }, 1000);
            prepend_items();
        });
    });

}

function prepend_items(){
    $(this).prependTo('#inventory');
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[jQuery's animate](http://api.jquery.com/animate/) is asynchronous so code that follows it in series is executed immediately after the animation is queued, but before it actually starts animating. You can pass `prepend_items` as a callback to animate, to have it execute when the animation completes.

Change:

```
        }, 1000);
        prepend_items();
```

To:

```
        }, 1000, prepend_items);
```

Comment: That works like a charm. However, now the prepended items disappear. Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: The box have position:absolute; and a left value. That made it "disappear". Thank you for your help!